# Algorithm to calculate the sum of a mathematical series

Tags: algorithm, math, sum, series

Recently I came across a online [tool](http://onsolver.com/sum.php), which given a summation calculates its formula. I have tried for many such summations and has given me correct answer.

I was curious as to which algorithm does it use to solve it.

**EDIT:** It turns out the tool uses wolframaplha api's. But even if you search on wolfram alpha you will get the same result.

Comment: I think that the only way to learn what algorithm *that particular site* uses is to ask the developers. That said, this is pretty interesting!

Comment: @templatetypedef Even if I ask, I am not sure they will reveal it

Comment: It seems to use Wolfram Alpha, judging from the result pane HTML, which begins `<iframe class="wolframAlphaWidgetResults"`.  Of course, that's probably not really the answer you wanted ;)

Comment: A very rough description of what it does is here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#7441 in the Sums and Products section. *Sum and Product use over 100 pages of Wolfram Language code.* suggests that, as you would expect, it is not some simple elegant algorithm.

Comment: It is probably incomplete/wrong. When I try to calculate (0.9)^x from x=1..infty , it say sum is infinite.

Comment: @ElKamina I checked and it gives 9 for me. Is that the correct answer. Anyway that website uses wolfram alpha in background. You can check it out yourself: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+0.9%5Ex+for+x+%3D+1+to+infinity

Comment: I think this question can also be like `how does R or MatLab are able to calculate the sum of a series` which is a question better asked on http://math.stackexchange.com & the answer won't look like an algorithm

Comment: I hope you are not trying to inflate search engine ratings by having a link from SO to that site?..

Comment: @Valentas No I am not. I am a curious computer scientist, who wants to know how things work. Anyway now there are many other features search engine relies on than on backlinks.

Comment: The question's too broad I think. Really, it's asking "how does symbolic computation work?"